# Unloading ViewControllers from Apple's PageControl Example + UINavigationController's Relationship to its RootViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I modified Apple's PageControl example to dynamically load various navigation controllers (along with their root view controllers) into the scroll view.  I also added a technique that attempts to unload a navigation controller when it's no longer needed.  I've only been at ObjC for a little over a month, so I'm not sure if I'm doing the unloading correctly.  Please see my code below, followed by my questions.

---

**First I create a mutable array and fill it with nulls, just like Apple does:**

```
// Create dummy array for viewControllers array, fill it with nulls, and assign to viewControllers
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= kNumberOfPages; i++)
{
    [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.viewControllers = array;
[array release];
```

**...Later, I fill the array with UINavigationController objects like so (this is just partial code, please excuse the missing parts...the main idea is that I alloc a couple of things, assign them and then release):**

```
id controller = [[classForViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(classForViewController) bundle:nil];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [controller release];
    [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:navController];
    [navController release];
```

**...Finally, if a page doesn't need to be loaded anymore I do this:**

```
[self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

---

**Questions:**

1. My understanding is that once I replace the navigation controller in my viewControllers array with null, the array releases the navigation controller.  Thus the navigation controller's retain count hits zero and it no longer takes up memory.  Is this correct?
2. What about the root view controller inside the navigation controller?  Do I need to do anything with it or does it get released automatically once the navigation controller's retain count hit zero?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Any object put into a collection is sent a `retain` message. Likewise any object removed from a collection is sent a `release` message, the cause of the removal is irrelevant.
2. Yes, all objects will release all the objects it owns when they are released.

This all boils down to the simple principle of ownership that Cocoa defines:

- You own the object if you received it as return value by calling a method that:

  1. Is named `alloc` or `new`.
  2. Contains the word *copy*, such as `copy` and `mutableCopy`.
- You own the object if you call `retain`.
- You may only call `release` and `autorelease` on objects you own.
- You *must* release all owned objects in your `dealloc` methods.

There is just one exception; delegates are never owned. This is to avoid circular references and the memory leaks they cause.

As a side effect this also means that when you yourself are implementing a method, you **must** return an auto released object unless you are implementing `new`, or a method with *copy* in it's name. Objects returned as out arguments are always autoreleased.

Follow this strictly and Objective-C can be treated as if it is garbage collected 95% of the time.

Comment: Thanks.  In retrospect it seems obvious and I feel kind of dumb for asking this question, but I just needed to confirm my understanding :)

Comment: Most things in Cocoa are obvious when you figure them out. Sometimes figuring them out can be quite hard since Cocoa is not much like anything else :).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably yes, once your retain count reaches zero (however or whenever that happens) your object will receive the `dealloc` message.  You can put a breakpoint to ensure that is happening.  Instruments comes with a Leaks utility that should help you find memory problems, it's a great tool and I suggest using it frequently.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "do anything to it".  I presume you mean release it.  The general pattern is that if you `alloc` or `retain`, you `release`.  You can roughly guess if there is going to be a problem if your allocs and retains outnumber your releases (or vice versa, you don't want to double release).